# cash on delivery enable disable when coupen code is applied opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I want to disable cash on delivery payment method option for some specific products. My opencart version is 2.1.0.2.I want to show cash on delivery method only for specific products and need to hide other payment options.Also,when coupon code is applied disable cod.

How can I do this?Please tell me if anyone know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making COD available only for certain products check this extension below :

https://www.cartbinder.com/store/cash-on-delivery-based-on-category-and-product-in-cart?utm_source=stackoverflow